# Footer disappears when using tikzpicture with \pause in beamer

Tags: footer, beamer

I want to have a sort of animation with each child of a root node appearing on a click. It works well except that the footer appears only when all animations complete for a slide. Maybe some can help fix the minimum reproducible example code below or propose another solution. Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Madrid}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblio}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title[tikzpicture with beamer]{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{tikzpicture}{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm]

\node (root) [process] {root};
\node (child1) [process, below of=root, xshift=-4cm] {child1};
\draw [arrow] (root) -- (child1);

\pause 
\node (child2) [process, below of=root, xshift=0cm] {child2};
\draw [arrow] (root) -- (child2);

\pause 
\node (child3) [process, below of=root, xshift=4cm] {child3};
\draw [arrow] (root) -- (child3);

\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but `\tikzstyle` is deprecated, you should transition to `\tikzset` instead

Comment: Could you possibly convert the solution using `\tikzset`? Thanks

Comment: That's totally unrelated to the questions at hand. You could ask a new questions about this

Comment: For others who may be interested, it was as simple as replacing `\tikzstyle{process}...` with this: `\tikzset{process/.style = {rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black, fill=orange!30}}`

Comment: I had the same problem. Solved it by mixing `\pause` with overlay, add `\onslide<1->` in the block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `\pause` in this situation, that's a very crude command. You can use overlays instead:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Madrid}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblio}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikzset{
  startstop/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30},
  io/.style={trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30},
  process/.style={rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black, fill=orange!30},
  decision/.style={diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30},
  arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title[tikzpicture with beamer]{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{tikzpicture}{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm]

\node (root) [process] {root};
\node (child1) [process, below of=root, xshift=-4cm] {child1};
\draw [arrow] (root) -- (child1);

\node<+(1)-> (child2) [process, below of=root, xshift=0cm] {child2};
\draw<.(1)-> [arrow] (root) -- (child2);

\node<+(1)-> (child3) [process, below of=root, xshift=4cm] {child3};
\draw<.(1)-> [arrow] (root) -- (child3);

\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]